# HTML table with TD padding in email

Tags: html, email, outlook

I've got a problem with a table inside an email.
The table looks good in the browser and in Gmail but not in Outlook 2007/10/13. It goes wrong with the padding in the right table cell I think.
Some website say that padding isn't fully supported in email clients.

Does anyone have some suggestions for me?

Here is an image of the browser and Gmail:
[image]

Here is an image of Outlook:
[image]

Here is the full code of the table:

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0" style="width: 600px; white-space: normal;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 100px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #000000;">
      <p>a</p>
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 25px; width: 416px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #000000;">
      <p>b</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: try adding *{ padding:0; margin:0; } to the top of your css file

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by adding an extra table inside a `<td>`.
Then I moved the padding from the `<td>` to the cellpadding of the table.
Works great in the most common mail clients.

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0" style="width: 600px; white-space: normal;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 100px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #000000;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p>a</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 416px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #000000;">
      <table cellpadding="25">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p>b</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```